# get the points inside a polygon and filter them

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geojson, shapefile

i am trying to sort markers added to my map, accordong to areas (governerates), i have them as .zip shapefile, I am able to -[Using this](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile)-to get the polygons and add them to the map with popups and everything. what i have been trtying to do is test if the markers are inside each polygon so i can filter them later. all tries till now have not worked.this is the full code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="" lang="en"><head>
<style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    
    </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>LSAAEQ - Accidents Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />  
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
  <script src="/Scripts/shp.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/leaflet.shpfile.js"></script>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-pip/v0.0.2/leaflet-pip.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p hidden id = "p1"></p>
        <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:1000px; padding-top:100px;"></div>
        <script>
  //creating layers
    lkj = 0;
            var cities = new L.LayerGroup();
            var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                    mbUrl = 'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var grayscale = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {id: 'remote-sensing.n8k508ak', attribution: mbAttr, accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVtb3RlLXNlbnNpbmciLCJhIjoiYWNiYzg0ZWU2Mjk3ZTU5NjE4MmQyZWEzZTY2ZWNlYjIifQ.U7mp4MXdcjaIwW_syAqriQ'})
                    , streets = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {id: 'remote-sensing.84f6c85a', attribution: mbAttr, accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVtb3RlLXNlbnNpbmciLCJhIjoiYWNiYzg0ZWU2Mjk3ZTU5NjE4MmQyZWEzZTY2ZWNlYjIifQ.U7mp4MXdcjaIwW_syAqriQ'});
            //create and add the layers to the map
   var map = L.map('map', {
                center: [33.9, 35.877],
                zoom: 10,
                layers: [streets, cities]
            });
           //the directory to the geojson data
            var dataurl = '/reporting/data.geojson';
   // get the geoJson data from url
     $.getJSON(dataurl, function (data) {
                var st = JSON.stringify(data);
     shpfile = new L.Shapefile('/resources/LBN_medium.zip',{
   onEachFeature:function(feature, layer) { layer.bindPopup("<span> "+feature.properties.NAME_1+"</span><br /><span> "+feature.properties.NAME_2+"</span><br /><span> "+feature.properties.VARNAME_3+"</span>"); }});
   shpfile.addTo(map);
   alert(shpfile);
  // asd = shpfile.getLayer(20); //your feature id here
   //alert(asd.feature.properties.NAME_1);
   //call the function to create the cluster sending the json data as a string
                Creation(st,shpfile);
            });
            function Creation(geo,shpfile) {
    results = leafletPip.pointInLayer([33.9, 35.8], shpfile,true);
    k = results.toString();
   //alert(shpfile.feature.properties.NAME_1);
   alert(typeof(results));
   alert("Testing...");
   //create the cluster object
   var markers = L.layerGroup();//new L.markerClusterGroup();
   var markers2 = new L.markerClusterGroup();
   //operations to get coordinates
                var lat = [];
                var lon = [];
                var coorM = geo.match(/\d{2}\.\d+\D\d{2}\.\d+/g);
                var len = coorM.length;
                var coorA = coorM[0].split(",");
                lon[0] = coorA[0];
                lat[0] = coorA[1];
   //create markers
                var mymark = new L.marker([lat[0], lon[0]],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
    mymark.bindPopup("<b>Accident</b><br>this is marker number 1 with coordinates :["+lat[0]+","+lon[0]+"]").openPopup();
   //add to the marker group
    markers.addLayer(mymark);
                for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    coorA = coorM[i].split(",");
                    lon[i] = coorA[0];
                    lat[i] = coorA[1];
                    mymark = new L.marker([lat[i], lon[i]],{time: "2015-10-1 08:42:26+01"});
     
     mymark.bindPopup("<b>Accident</b><br>this is marker number "+(i+1)+ " with coordinates :["+lat[i]+","+lon[i]+"]").openPopup();
                    markers.addLayer(mymark);
                }
              //  map.addLayer(markers);
    layerf = L.featureGroup();
 var mymark = new L.marker([33.68,35.12],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
layerf.addLayer(mymark);
 var mymark = new L.marker([35.68,35.53],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
layerf.addLayer(mymark);
 var mymark = new L.marker([33.9,35.8],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
 layerf.addLayer(mymark);
     layert = L.featureGroup();
 var mymark = new L.marker([33.23,35.753],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
layert.addLayer(mymark);
 var mymark = new L.marker([34.36,35.3575],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
layert.addLayer(mymark);
 var mymark = new L.marker([33.753,35.29],{time: "2015-11-10 08:42:26+01"});
 
 layert.addLayer(mymark);
 markers2.addLayer(layert);
 markers2.addLayer(layerf); 
 markers2.addLayer(markers);
 map.addLayer(markers2);
            }
   //baselayers for map
            var baseLayers = {
                "Grayscale": grayscale,
                "Streets": streets
            };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

note: some comments are just for debugging. if you have at least an idea on how to start it is most appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use turf.js `turf.inside(point, polygon)` function http://turfjs.org/docs/#inside to test if the point is inside polygon.

Comment: Yes it does. But once you have L.Marker, you can call function toGeoJSON() to get the GeoJSON representation.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: This is an old one, fixed.